# URL filters for Power BI SPA

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I have an SPA, that renders properly and works as expected. I need to preset the filters in the report, when I try this with the URL it renders but the filter isn't applied. I have found many guides including Microsofts own documentation, they all explain it the same way so I'm pretty sure I'm formatting it correctly. My question is, is this even possible or does it need to be done using javascript in the app itself? I've read in the documentation this is possible for embedded reports, but I'm unsure if an SPA is considered an embedded report. TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Single Page Applications (SPAs) offer support for URL filters. You need to add query string parameters at the end of Embed URL, to get the embedded report filtered.

Here is the sample Embed URL after adding parameters.

[https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId={}&groupId={}&filter=Store%2fTerritory%20eq%20%27NC%27](https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=%7B%7D&groupId=%7B%7D&filter=Store%2fTerritory%20eq%20%27NC%27)

Refer the [URL Filter documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-url-filters) for more details. Go through the limitations and make sure your scenario is supported.

If the issue still persists, you need to provide more details.